# Programmatic list of Webform elements?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am building a D8 module that, for configuration, needs a list of webforms and their fields (just the entity reference fields, but I am not picky)

I can get the webforms with this:

```
  $webforms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->loadMultiple(null);
```

But once I get the returned elements `(Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::__set_state)`, how can I fetch the elements in the webform referenced?

Comment: Are you trying to get the values a user entered? or just the field names the form contains?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the form's field names, and found the result myself.... eventually.  Posted below.

Answer (score 9):

By trawling through the code, I found this handy function in the Entity code, and it works perfectly:

```
 $elements = $webform->getElementsDecodedAndFlattened();
```

This gives a nice array of the elements in the webform itself.

If you want the results of a submission, grab that entity and use:

```
$data = $entity->getData();
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The complete code for fetching the webform elements are listed below:

```
  $webform = Webform::load('webform_id'); //replace webform_id with the webform id
  if ($webform) {
    $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('webform');
    $elements = $webform->getElementsDecodedAndFlattened();
  }
```